# How to display in QGIS Map Tips an image with absolute path written in the layer?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, image, html, maptips

I am trying to display the images of a layer with the "map tip" function.

The absolute path of each picture `(D:\ ... \ ...\...jpg)` is written in a field called "path".

I tried to build the HTML code thanks to other posts, but I can't display the image.

Is this code correct?

```
<div style="width:400; height:400">
<img src= [% "path" %] " width="400"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to replace the [% "path" %] with the actual path of one of your image to see if that work ?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work.
I see a blank image with a blue question mark.
This path is correct because the QGIS module/widget "attached" is configured correctly and works.

Comment: I had gotten the idea from there, but I discovered the catch. It was missing some : " ".
Attached is the working code.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code, this works:

```
<div style="width:600; height:600">
<div><img src= "file:///[% "path" %]" width="600" /></div>
</div>
```